How to setup a home lab with a custom domain name?
I just set up my first home lab, and really enjoying it. Currently, I access all of my services in the browser through their IPs.
How would I set up a domain name?  I actually have an entry in my host file, but I still need to specify a port in the when accessing the service in my browser.  For example, heres the host file entry:
Host File Entry
192.x.x.x      homelab

I have MkDocs running on port 8005, so to access that in the browser, I'd go to homelab:8005.
The desired outcome is this --> homelab/mkdocs:

Do I have to purchase a domain name?
I've seen mentions of Traefik. Could I just use this to get the desired outcome?

Note: I have no desire to expose any of this outside of my home network.

Generally speaking, domain names have nothing to do with port numbers. The only thing they handle is address translation, just like your /etc/hosts file already does – but if you have a webapp on a non-standard port, you'll still have to specify the :8005 even if you have a domain name.
(Some services use SRV records to let DNS provide a port number, but HTTP currently doesn't.)
To avoid having to specify the :8005, you instead need some HTTP software that would accept requests on the standard port :80 and relay them to the real server. Traefik can do that, as can many other "HTTP reverse proxy" services (including even Nginx or Apache httpd).
Having a domain name (either real or faked through /etc/hosts) is only useful in that your web browser is more likely to recognize the input as a real URL and not as a search query, as e.g. Chrome really likes to treat "foo/bar" as a Google search if you omit the "http://" whereas it's more likely to accept "foo.example.com/bar" as-is.
You can specify multiple component names in your /etc/hosts, e.g. 127.0.0.1 foo.example.com. For a homelab, though, you might want to set up a local DNS server that would host a domain (either a real one or made-up) – that way you could easily make it known to the rest of your LAN.
(Dnsmasq is a common choice for home networks but its configuration is slightly weird, while Bind9 is "the Apache httpd of DNS" and Unbound is primarily a resolver that recently gained the ability to host DNS zones.)
